# Measure Theory Problem: $\lim_{n\to\infty} n \cdot \mu(E_n) = 0$

Tags: measure-theory

$(\mathbf X,M,\mu)$ measure space, $f : \mathbf X \to [0;\infty]$ a measurable function such that Integral $\int_X f \, d\mu < \infty$.

If $E_n = \{x \in \mathbf X : n + 1 \ge f(x) > n\}$ then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n \cdot \mu(E_n) = 0$$

I can't figure it out: I thought about the fact that $E_n$ are a partition of $X$, so I could use countable additivity there, but I don't know if $\mu$ is a finite measure so I can't show any convergence.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: How can you rewrite $E_{n}$ using $f^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Start with $\infty>\int_X f\,d\mu =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{E_{n}}f\,d\mu\ge \sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_{E_{n}}n\,d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\mu(E_{n})$.

Comment: Thank you guys! It always seems so trivial when you see the solution! Have a nice day :)

Comment: To conceptually connect your comment (that you don't know if $\mu$ is a finite measure) to the given solutions: We do know that $$\nu(E):=\int_E fd\mu$$ is a finite measure on $M$. Then since $(E_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are pairwise disjoint, $\nu(E_n)\to 0$.   But $\nu(E_n)\geqslant n\mu(E_n)$.